# Pytest paramaterized fixture not returning yielded object, only returning tuple?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, pytest-django

I'm working to setup a fixture that will open a headless (or headed) instance of a web browser for some end to end testing. I am using Django with pytest and pytest-django.

I'd like to be able to paramaterize the test class with the browsers I'd like to use and whether or not they are headless in a fashion like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("browser_fixture", [("chrome", False)])
@pytest.mark.slow()
class TestEndToEnd:
```

In my `conftest.py` I have set it up like this:

```
def create_browser(browser_name, headless=True):
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        options = ChromeOptions()
        if headless:
            options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
            options.add_argument("--disable-gui")
        return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        options = FirefoxOptions()
        if headless:
            options.add_argument("--headless")
            options.add_argument("--disable-gui")
        return webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported browser: {browser_name}")


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def browser_fixture(request):
    browser_name, headless = request.param
    browser = create_browser(browser_name, headless=headless)
    yield browser
    browser.quit()
```

My test looks like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("browser_fixture", [("chrome", False)])
@pytest.mark.slow()
class TestEndToEnd:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, browser_fixture, live_server):
        management.call_command("create_project_data", verbosity=0)
        self.browser = browser_fixture
        # At this point I would expect the browser to open
        # but instead self.browser is just the tuple: `('chrome', False)`
        self.live_server_url = live_server.url

    def login_user(
        self, username=None, password="test", user=None, browser=None
    ):
        if browser is None:
            raise Exception("No browser provided")
        # The logic to login here 


    def test_as_admin(self):
        standard_user = User.objects.first()
        self.login_user(standard_user.username)
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + "/mills/")
        assert "Mills" in self.browser.title
```

The issue appears to be in the `setup` method. It should be opening a browser and then the test should be using that to call the login (to login the user) and do the testing it needs to.

Instead, the `browser_fixture` fixture is just returning the tuple.

Any ideas on where to go here?

Comment: Perfecto. You've nailed it! Want to make that the answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `indirect=True`:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("browser_fixture", [("chrome", False)], indirect=True)
@pytest.mark.slow()
class TestEndToEnd:
    ...
```

Without indirection, the first argument (`"browser_fixture"`) defines a variable that can be used in the test, which will be assigned each of the parameter values of the second argument as usual. If there is a fixture of the same name, that fixture is just hidden and cannot be used in the test.

The [indirect](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) argument tells `pytest` to redirect the parameter values to the fixture of that name instead. Setting `indirect=True` is a shortcut to saying "redirect the parameter for all names in the first argument",
which is what is mostly needed. It is equivalent to `indirect=["browser_fixture"]`, which is a form that can be handy if you want to [mix direct and indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments).

As an aside: usually a fixture is not called "xxx_fixture". In your case, it is usually called "driver" or "browser". This make the usage a bit more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and links. I appreciate the explanation greatly and helped me to understand the indirect functionality!